# How can I connect my React app to a PHP file?

Tags: php, reactjs, docker, apache

I'm trying to connect a simple contact form to send emails using React and PHP.

The problem I have is that every tutorial or article I've found either leaves out key parts that probably seem simple yet to a complete PHP beginner are all the difference between a working app or not. I have basically no experience with PHP and connecting a PHP file to a React app, I've downloaded Docker and Apache (yet have no idea how they fit into the picture), where to place the PHP file (if it even matters), how to host the PHP development server, etc...

I'm aware I should ideally spend some time reading through and actually learning PHP, it's something I plan to do, yet I'm pressed for time so that isn't currently an option.

The code I'm using is from this article https://blog.bitsrc.io/how-to-build-a-contact-form-with-react-js-and-php-d5977c17fec0

I currently have the PHP file placed like so: projectfolder -> php-folder -> index.php

and the React like so: projectfolder -> react-folder -> src --> (all the react files)

again, all the code is from the tutorial I linked and all I did was place the PHP from the article into the index.php file like above, and the same thing with the React code from the article (with the path names corrected) so I'm sure it's something I'm missing with the backend like setting up Docker or Apache, or possibly the file placement.

Sorry if this seems like a really broad question, essentially I just need to know the steps for correctly connecting a PHP file with a React app to send emails from a contact form.

Thanks

Comment: Your mindset is wrong. You shouldn't think like "connecting react with PHP". Instead, you send an HTTP request to a server (you don't know if it's PHP or something else), then that server returns a response.

Comment: Do you recommend any resources to learn from?